# Embed google calendar in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

How can I embed google calendar in an iPhone app using the latest version of xcode (4.3.3)?

Comment: Did it change from previous versions of xCode?

Comment: Really broad question. Go and lookup how to use UIWebView and the latest version of Xcode is 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would use `UIWebView`. That would be the easiest. Then just have it load to the calendar  sign in on googles side. Like this in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
[YourWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                   @"Your URL Here"]]];
```